# VLOOKUP NO PYTHON USANDO MERGE

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Eu possuo um DataFrame chamado `df` com uma coluna de países em diversas línguas e um outro DataFrame chamado `ct` que eu possuo uma coluna com os países em diversas línguas e outra coluna com os mesmos países traduzidos pro inglês. Quero que uma coluna do DataFrame `df` tenha a tradução desses países para o inglês consultado no DataFrame `ct` como se fosse um VLOOKUP. Tentei usar o `merge`, mas ele não está pesquisando corretamente.

```py
ct = pd.DataFrame(country, columns=['RAW ORIGIN COUNTRY', 'ORIGIN COUNTRY', 'REGION'])

ct.rename(columns={'RAW ORIGIN COUNTRY':'Raw Origin'}, inplace=True)

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Raw Origin', 'Origin']

df['Origin'] = pd.merge(df, ct[['Raw Origin', 'ORIGIN COUNTRY']], on='Raw Origin', how='left')
```

quando eu exporto pro excel fica assim:

[image: resultado final]

Comment: Para conseguirmos reproduzir o erro seria adequado colocar ao menos 3 registros do ct e do df.

Comment: O comando `pd.merge` retorna um `dataframe`. Isso faz com que a coluna 'Origin' de `df` seja um dataframe e não `series`. Era isso que vc queria?

Comment: Tenta incluir no "on" os colchetes. on=['Raw Origin']